# Addchild - object not appearing on stage from external class

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having problem with "DiamondEnemy" objects created in external class "Level" not appearing on the stage. I'm trying to retrieve a random enemy from "EnemyNotReleasedArray" at intervals and add them to screen through "enemyOnScreen" sprite.

Please note I have not 100% finished with all the functionality; so it may seem a little weird. I don't want to go further until I can actually get it working.

update: I create a new "level" object from a separate document class called "main".

```
package  {

    import DiamondEnemy;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Level extends MovieClip {

        private const START_DELAY_SECONDS:uint = 1000;
        private var EnemyNotReleasedArray:Array = new Array();
        private var startDelay:Timer;
        private var enemyOnScreen: Sprite;

        public function Level(NumberDiamonds:uint) 
        {
            // load the required enemies into the array
            loadEnemyArray(NumberDiamonds);

            //setup up sprite, for enemies that will appear on the screen
            enemyOnScreen = new Sprite();
            addChildAt(enemyOnScreen, numChildren);

            // create delay timer before enemies can start appearing on screen
            startDelay = new Timer(START_DELAY_SECONDS,1);

            // set eventlistener that once delay finishes 
            startDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, releaseRandomEnemy);
            startDelay.start();

            //setup up sprite, for enemies that will appear on the screen
            enemyOnScreen = new Sprite();
            addChild(enemyOnScreen);

        }

        // creates the requested number of enemies type into EnemyNotReleasedArray so they can be released later
        private function loadEnemyArray(numDiamonds:uint)
        {
            // use requested number diamonds enemies - to create diamond enemy objects
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < numDiamonds; i++)
            {
                var diamond:DiamondEnemy = new DiamondEnemy();
                EnemyNotReleasedArray.push(diamond);
            }
        }

        // selects a random enemy from EnemyNotReleasedArray and resizes the array so enemy is no longer in it
        private function releaseRandomEnemy(evt:TimerEvent)
        {
            var arrayLength:uint = EnemyNotReleasedArray.length;

            // check make sure array is not empty, if empy level is over
            if (arrayLength > 0)
            {
                var randomArrayIndex = Math.ceil(Math.random() * arrayLength) -1;

                /// adding random enemy to sprite object
                enemyOnScreen.addChild(EnemyNotReleasedArray[randomArrayIndex]);
                trace(EnemyNotReleasedArray[randomArrayIndex]);

                //remove the enemy from array and make element null
                EnemyNotReleasedArray.removeAt(randomArrayIndex)

                //tempory array to store non-null values
                var tempArray:Array = new Array();

                // cycle through EnemyNotReleasedArray and store all values that are not null into temp array
                for each(var enemy in  EnemyNotReleasedArray)
                {
                    if (enemy != null)
                    {
                        tempArray.push(enemy)
                    }
                }

                // save temp array value into EnemyNotReleasedArray
                EnemyNotReleasedArray = tempArray;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("no more enemies left in array");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

document class "Main":

```
package  {
    import Level;
    import DiamondEnemy;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Main() 
        {
            var level:Level = new Level(1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you use this class? Is this your document class? Or does your document class instantiate that class?

Comment: I have a separate document class called "main" that I create a "Level" object from. Would it matter where I create the level object from? eg either timeline or document class?

Comment: Thank you for the update, but could you show the exact and entire code in your document class that deals with the `Level` object? Please [edit] your question and include the code. If your document class is not too long yet, feel free to simply post the entire code just so that no important part that's possibly responsible for the undesired behaviour is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Iv added the document class code, not really much too it at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display list is a hierarchical graph, often called a tree.

Everything that's directly or indirectly connected to the root node is displayed. The root node is the `Stage` object. While possible, nothing of your own code should actually `addChild()` to this object. (for reasons out of the scope of this answer)

The only child of the `Stage` is the instance of your document class that's created  when your .swf file is executed. This instance is automatically added to the `Stage` object, too, which is why you never have to add the document class to anything but it's still visible.

The constructor of your `Main` class looks like this:

```
    public function Main() 
    {
        var level:Level = new Level(1);
    }
```

The problem is that while you successfully create the `Level` object, it is never added to the above described hierarchy that's usually called the "display list". `level` is not connected to the root node, which is why it is not displayed. You can still add children to `level`, but they won't be visible either for the same reason: that is, `level` is not visible.

To fix this, add `level` to your document class like so:

```
    public function Main() 
    {
        var level:Level = new Level(1);
        addChild(level);
    }
```

---

Btw. you have this code twice:

```
        //setup up sprite, for enemies that will appear on the screen
        enemyOnScreen = new Sprite();
        addChildAt(enemyOnScreen, numChildren);
```

and

```
        //setup up sprite, for enemies that will appear on the screen
        enemyOnScreen = new Sprite();
        addChild(enemyOnScreen);
```

but you only need it once. The second one is all you need.

And neither one of your two classes should `extends MovieClip` as non of them have a time line. Use `extends Sprite` unless you are actually dealing with MovieClips.

Comment: omg THANK YOU so much, you have made my day! after hours of frustration! :)